# Xcode Archive: Is that possible to archive without login user & password

Tags: xcode, archive

Is that possible to Archive application in Xcode with .p12 & certificate & .pem & provisionProfile, but without login user & password.

I have not got the account & password yet. The problem is do I need to got the account ? because It's boring to ask the client to give `SMS` time by time if I have to use account & password.

But I have all the files like `.p12` & `certificate` & `.pem` & `provisionProfile`
Can I archive app in Xcode ?
Or can I archive by command line ?

Currently Xcode give error of

```
Code Signing Error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "_______" with a private key was found.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.2'
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.2'
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.2'
```